# Smallest possible cardinality of the generating set of a group

Tags: group-theory, terminology, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

A very useful invariant associated to any group is the smallest possible cardinality of a generating set that generates that group. This is always guaranteed to exist, no matter what the group, at least given the axiom of choice. To see this, we can simply look at the set of all generating sets for that group, then map each element in that set to the cardinal it's in bijection with. Then, we have a set of cardinals, and at least using the axiom of choice we know this must have a least element because cardinals are well-ordered.

For a finitely-generated free abelian group it's equal to the rank of the group, but in general it's different. For instance, the group $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ has rank 0, but the smallest generating set has cardinality 1. It also is well-defined even for non-finitely-generated groups: the group $\Bbb Q$ isn't finitely generated, and the smallest generating set has cardinality $\aleph_0$. And so on.

Does this quantity have a name or play any kind of important role in the usual approach to group theory?

Comment: $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ has a generating set of size $1.$

Comment: Many authors call it the "rank." See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_a_group).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews, edited.

Comment: Thanks @MoisheKohan, although I guess there are two meanings of rank? For abelian groups, for instance, the rank of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/2Z$ would be $1$ (what I guess Wikipedia calls the "torsion-free rank"), whereas with this I think it'd be $2$.

Comment: More than two, the word rank has other meanings as well, even in algebra.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I just mean within group theory.

Comment: Me too: Theory of algebraic groups and Lie groups is a subfield of group theory.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia the torsion free part of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$ so it has rank $1$. This is because of the generators $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ the first has infinite order and the second has finite order.

Comment: @CyclotomicField yeah, that's what I'm saying. The torsion-free rank as an abelian group is 1, but the general group-theoretic rank in the sense we are talking about above would be 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert my comment to an answer:

The (relatively) standard terminology is that the minimal cardinality of a generating set of a group $G$ is called the **rank** of $G$. It is primarily used in the case of finitely generated groups, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_a_group). One of the earlier uses of this notion was in the proof of Grushko's theorem: The free product decomposition of a finitely generated group eventually terminates. Grushko proved this by establishing the equality:
$$
rank(G_1*G_2)= rank(G_1) + rank(G_2),
$$
provided that $G=G_1*G_2$ is finitely generated.

It is an unfortunate fact that the word "rank" has other meanings in group theory as well: In the theory of algebraic groups (and Lie groups) it means something completely different (for semisimple algebraic groups, this is the dimension of a maximal split torus) and, as you know, it has a different meaning for abelian groups as well.

Comment: OK. So let's say I'm talking about the group $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. Would I say the "rank" is 2 and the "torsion-free rank" is 1? Because I thought that when talking about f.g. abelian groups the term "rank" without additional clarification is used to refer to the torsion-free rank. Or at least that's what I learned recently...

Comment: Also, you wrote $rank(G_1*G_2)= rank(G_1) + rank(G_2)$ above -- should that be $rank(G_1*G_2) \leq rank(G_1) + rank(G_2)$?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia: I meant what I wrote, an upper bound is a trivial result and Grushko's theorem is not.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I misread; you are talking about the *free* product, not the direct product. OK, thanks. I am still looking for clarification on rank vs torsion-free rank above if you have any insight.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia: As I said, the word "rank" is ambiguous even if you are discussing f.g. abelian groups. Personally, I would use two different notations, say, $arank$ for the rank of the free abelian quotient and $rank$ for the rank as in my answer. Then $arank(Z+Z_2)=1$ while $rank(Z+Z_2)=2$.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. The other reason I was confused about Grushko's theorem is that you say "Grushko proved this by establishing the *inequality*" above, but then you follow it with the *equality* of $rank(G_1*G_2)= rank(G_1) + rank(G_2)$. Is the original sentence a typo for "equality"?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia: Thank you for noticing, it's a typo, I will correct it now.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to this,  there's the fact that the quotient of a finite $p-$group by its *Frattini subgroup*, $G/\Phi(G)$, has order $p^k$, where $k$ is the minimal size of a generating set for $G$.

For reference,  the Frattini is the intersection of all maximal subgroups (or the whole group if there are no maximal subgroups).