# Definition of the rank of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology

Given some ring $R$, we can ask what the cardinality of the smallest possible [generating set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603345/generating-set-of-a-ring-and-the-empty-product/4603394) is.

This is an invariant for $R$ that I would like to call the "rank" of $R$, as it is basically the same idea as the [group-theoretic rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4603268/52694), but for rings. If we treat the ring as a $\Bbb Z$-algebra, this would seem to lead to a similar notion of the rank of an algebra on an arbitrary ring.

The main question is about terminology. Is there a term for this, and is it equally useful to look at as it is for groups?

It looks like there is something *slightly* different which is also called the rank of a ring in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2017.1392540#:%7E:text=The%20rank%20rk(R)%20of,rank%20of%20some%20ring%20R.). In this paper, we instead look at the smallest generating set of *every ideal* in $R$, and then take the maximum of all of them. I guess this is a different notion of generating set we are talking about than the generating set of a ring.

Questions:

1. Is the original thing I'm talking about useful (cardinality of minimal generating set of the entire ring) and does it have a standardized name?
2. This paper I linked to above instead has us look at the cardinality of the minimal generating set for each ideal, then take the supremum and call *that* the rank. Is there some point to this? <s>Can a ring have an ideal with a larger minimal generating set than the ring itself?</s> **EDIT** - I guess we are talking about two different types of "generating set" here, see below.
3. Is there any reason to prefer one or the other?

EDIT: I guess we are talking about two different types of generating set. As a ring, $\Bbb Z$ is generated by the empty set, but taking the entire ring as an ideal of itself, it's generated by $\{1\}$. So I guess I am just curious if the two things are related at all.

Comment: It seems both difficult to compute and not particularly useful for anything.

Comment: That is a good point; I guess we are talking about two different types of generating set. I have edited the question accordingly. I guess the question is if the original thing I was talking about has a name. Is that the thing you are saying is related to the embedding dimension? I haven't studied much algebraic geometry and that link above is pretty dense...